# Search anywhere in the content instead of starting

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-datalist

This is an example taken from MDN.

```
<input list="browsers" />
<datalist id="browsers">
  <option value="Chrome">
  <option value="Firefox">
  <option value="Internet Explorer">
  <option value="Opera">
  <option value="Safari">
</datalist>
```

Currently, When I type E in the input element, no suggestion will appear.
I want to suggestions displayed if the input value element is anywhere in the option value instead of starting value.

**[Try It In JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/adavat/1/edit)**

Is it possible? Currently I'm using jquery Ui Autocomplete to accomplish this feature.
Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://github.com/mmurph211/Autocomplete)

Comment: The code you are showing is HTML5, so the functional implementation is browser specific and there are no events or other places where you could change/add functionality. So if you need that functionality you'll have to use jQuery Ui Autocomplete, or simular. You most likely could programm jQuery Ui Autocomplete to get it's data from the datalist.

Comment: Thank you guys. I think I should use jQuery Ui Autocomplete for now. But is damn slow when compared to the html5 Datalist. :(

Answer (score 1):

try twitter typeahead : https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js

It works with jQuery

Answer (score 1):

It depends, what browser do you use.
Firefox handles it as we would expect - searches within the text (tested on FF38).
Chrome is limited to search from the beginning of the text (tested on Ch43).